# PHP QUERY Loop?

Tags: php, select, loops

Basically I have a genealogy table where everybody has a child_id for themselves and a parent_id (both of which are fields in my table). My goal is to add + 1 to my vote field to each parent in a lineage.

So, I need to SELECT the parent_id from a row and update the vote. Then I need to select the parent from that row and update that parents vote. Then i need to select the parent from THAT row and do the same thing..over and over until I get to the very first ancestor and there are no more parents or children to update. Here are my select and update queries:

```
SELECT parent_id FROM profiles where child_id = $first_ancestor
UPDATE profiles SET votes = votes + 1 where child_id = parent_id
```

Do I use a loop? Or how do I do this? Thanks!

Comment: For dealing with trees of data, you may want to look into storing that data in a nested set. That makes things like this a lot easier.

Comment: @deceze that depends on the frequency of his updates

Answer (score 1):

I'd use a loop. To my knowledge, that's a limitation to relational databases. Some DBMS have better support for recursive queries than others though.

If you're up for it, you might want to check out something called [graph databases](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_database). Some of them has much better support for these kinds of operations than most relational databases have.

Check out:

- [CloudGraph](http://www.cloudgraph.com/) has an interesting "graph query language"
- [Neo4j](http://neo4j.org/) uses something they call "traversals", looks neat
- [InfoGrid](http://infogrid.org/)
- [GraphBase](http://graphbase.net/)